# Duplicate dynamic nodes on nested levels

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider

I have an issue with MVCSiteMapProvider as follows.

My MVC.siteMap:

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index" key="home">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Login/Register" controller="Login" action="Index"/>

    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Collections" clickable="false" key="nodeCollections">
        <mvcSiteMapNode title="Dynamic Nodes" controller="Collections" action="Index" clickable="true" dynamicNodeProvider="mysite.Utilities.DynamicNodeProvider, mysite.com" />
    </mvcSiteMapNode>

    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Categories" clickable="false" key="nodeCategories">
        <mvcSiteMapNode title="Dynamic Nodes" controller="Products" action="Index" clickable="true" dynamicNodeProvider="mysite.Utilities.DynamicNodeProvider, mysite.com" />
    </mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

My DynamicNodeProvider:

```
        foreach (var collection in collections)
        {
            var node = new DynamicNode
            {
                Title = collection.collection,
                Controller = "Collections",
                Action = "Index",
                ParentKey = "home",
                ChangeFrequency = ChangeFrequency.Weekly
            };
            node.RouteValues.Add("seocollection", collection.seoCollection);
            yield return node;
        }

        ////Get Categories Nodes
        // Create a node for each category 
        foreach (var category in categories)
        {
            var node = new DynamicNode
            {
                //Key = category.category,
                Title = category.category,
                Controller = "Products",
                Action = "Index",
                ParentKey = "home",
                ChangeFrequency = ChangeFrequency.Weekly
            };
            node.RouteValues.Add("seocategory", category.seocategory);
            yield return node2;
        }
```

And my HtmlHelper:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    @Html.MvcSiteMap().Menu("MenuHelperModel", SiteMaps.Current.FindSiteMapNodeFromKey("home"),true,true)
</div>
```

Although this works correctly, I'm getting duplicated results on the returned menu i.e. it shows:

Home
Login/Register
Collections
Collection A
Category A
Category B
Categories
Collection A
Category A
Category B

Am I binding incorrectly in the MVC.sitemap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I binding incorrectly in the MVC.sitemap?

Yes. You are getting duplicate results because you have the same dynamic node provider registered 2 times. In addition, you have specified to nest every node below the home node which will give you a flat structure.

First of all, to fix the nesting issue, you should specify a different parent key for each of your nested items than "home". Based on the way you have structured your XML, I am guessing that you don't want them under the "home" node.

```
    foreach (var collection in collections)
    {
        var node = new DynamicNode
        {
            Title = collection.collection,
            Controller = "Collections",
            Action = "Index",
            // Specify the node you want this node nested under
            ParentKey = "nodeCollections", 
            ChangeFrequency = ChangeFrequency.Weekly
        };
        node.RouteValues.Add("seocollection", collection.seoCollection);
        yield return node;
    }

    ////Get Categories Nodes
    // Create a node for each category 
    foreach (var category in categories)
    {
        var node = new DynamicNode
        {
            //Key = category.category,
            Title = category.category,
            Controller = "Products",
            Action = "Index",
            // Specify the node you want this node nested under
            ParentKey = "nodeCategories",
            ChangeFrequency = ChangeFrequency.Weekly
        };
        node.RouteValues.Add("seocategory", category.seocategory);
        yield return node2;
    }
```

Then, to fix your duplication issue, you either need to break your 1 dynamic node into 2 or simply to specify it only once in your XML. Note that the position where the dynamic node provider is declared doesn't matter - the parent key is what places all of the nodes in the appropriate place in the node hierarchy.

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index" key="home">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Login/Register" controller="Login" action="Index"/>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Collections" clickable="false" key="nodeCollections"/>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Categories" clickable="false" key="nodeCategories"/>
    <mvcSiteMapNode dynamicNodeProvider="mysite.Utilities.DynamicNodeProvider, mysite.com" />
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

The values that you specify in the XML become the *default* values in the dynamic node provider. They are not strictly necessary if they are already specified within the dynamic node provider.

Also note that if you split your 1 dynamic node provider into 2 it will be a bit more intuitive to work with than this example, but it isn't necessary from a technical standpoint.